# How can I correctly order a tilemap so that it appears on the bottom-most layer with Phaser?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have been working on a small game using Phaser and have mostly gotten it working, however collectively the various parts are not working correctly. For some odd reason, the main tilemap - meant to be a base layer, is set over everything else.

I have double checked this by removing the map, and have seen the asteroid shadows generated on screen. Even setting the asteroid group to a depth of 200 or more, the map still appears on top and using 'group.sort' seems to have no effect. How can I fix this?

```
GameObject.Engine = function() {};

GameObject.Engine.prototype = {
    init : function()
    { 
        this.map;
        this.cursors;
        this.mapLayer = System.add.group();
        this.mapLayer.z = 0;

        this.asteroidShadowGroup = System.add.group();
        this.asteroidShadowGroup.z = 200;

        this.mapSizeWidth = 1280;
        this.mapSizeHeight = 960;
        this.bufferZone = 60;


        System.world.setBounds(0, 0, this.mapSizeWidth, this.mapSizeHeight);
        this.initPhysics();
    },
    initPhysics :function()
    {
        System.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        this.asteroidShadowGroup.enableBody = true;
        this.asteroidShadowGroup.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;       
    },
    create : function()
    {
        this.map = System.add.tilemap('World');
        this.map.addTilesetImage('Tiles', 'Background');

        this.map.createLayer('BaseWorld');
        this.cursors = System.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

        this.buildAsteroids();
    },
    update: function() {

        this.asteroidShadowGroup.forEachExists(this.checkBoundaries, this);

        if (this.cursors.up.isDown)
        {
            System.camera.y -= 4;
        }
        else if (this.cursors.down.isDown)
        {
            System.camera.y += 4;
        }

        if (this.cursors.left.isDown)
        {
            System.camera.x -= 4;
        }
        else if (this.cursors.right.isDown)
        {
            System.camera.x += 4;
        }
    },
    checkBoundaries: function (sprite) {
        if (sprite.x < -this.bufferZone) {
            sprite.x = this.mapSizeWidth + this.bufferZone;
        } else if (sprite.x > this.mapSizeWidth + this.bufferZone) {
            sprite.x = -this.bufferZone;
        } 

        if (sprite.y < -this.bufferZone) {
            sprite.y = this.mapSizeHeight  + this.bufferZone;
        } else if (sprite.y > this.mapSizeHeight  + this.bufferZone) {
            sprite.y = -this.bufferZone;
        }
    },
    buildAsteroids: function () {

        for (var i=0; i < 8; i++ ) {

            var x;
            var y;

            x = System.rnd.integerInRange(0, this.mapSizeWidth);
            y = System.rnd.integerInRange(0, this.mapSizeHeight);

            this.createAsteroid(x, y);
        }   
    },
    createAsteroid: function (x, y) {
        var asteroid = this.asteroidShadowGroup.create(x, y, 'asteroids', System.rnd.integerInRange(0, 12));
        asteroid.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
        asteroid.angularVelocity = System.rnd.integerInRange(0, 360);

        var randomAngle = System.math.degToRad(System.rnd.angle());
        var randomVelocity = System.rnd.integerInRange(10, 40);

        System.physics.arcade.velocityFromRotation(randomAngle, randomVelocity, asteroid.body.velocity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and initialise your groups after creating `this.map` in your `create()` method.

Generally, if you want to add groups in different "z" layers the order you add them to the game matters.
For example if you have:

```
this.groupA = this.game.add.group();
this.groupB = this.game.add.group();
this.groupC = this.game.add.group();
```

then the rendering order will always be:

- groupA background
- groupB middle and
- groupC foreground

There are probably some methods like `bringToTop()` where you can manipulate the order, but you'd have to search the docs for that!

Comment: Whoops! That was the problem. I hadn't realized initializing the group first would force it to the bottom automatically.